# Having trouble with similar key prefixes, ie. "Tag1" is called instead of "Tag10" despite both existing

Tags: c#, arrays, string, algorithm, prefix

I have an array of valid prefixes, and let's say we have "tag1" and "tag10".
If I am removing prefixes so that "tag1Date" and "tag1Name" become just "Date" and "Name", the issue is that I end up also getting "0Date" and "0Name".
I've though about checking the character after "tag1" to see if it's a number or not, if so it must be a separate tag, but can't get it working.
Can't show code unfortunately because it's proprietary. All help welcome!

Comment: You either need to know the prefixes being removed or the outputs expected (from which you can deduce the prefix to remove)

Comment: Please provide more information on what's a valid tag. Is it user input and can be any string? If it's a well known list of string, just order them such that the most inclusive (tag10) gets checked before the least inclusive (tag1, ta, t, etc.)

Comment: Or split the string on a delimiter. This is not very answerable without more context, all we can do is throw ideas.

Comment: You should show the code you're using so folks can help with a targeted answer. How are you removing the tags?

Comment: You might not be able to share the exact code, but you still need to at least provide a [mcve].

Comment: If your tags all have the same pattern, you could probably easily use a Regex here. For example, `^\D+\d+` will match things of the form you have shown here (tag1, tag10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order your tags array in decending order then remove the prefix's.

For example
Array should be ["tag10", "tag1"]

Then you remove tag10 first then tag1

Comment: @NetMage `OrderByDescending(x => x)` should work, shouldn't it? Why specify length?

Comment: @RufusL I believe you are correct, but it feels to me like a risk given Unicode and linguistic sorting rules that might effect the order.